# Using lookback API for release scope change

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Assuming I have a specific release with a number of child stories I want to see how the stories for that release change over time (per iteration)

- I can use the v2 API to get a list of stories assigned to the release easily enough but I want to use the lookback API to go back an iteration (for example) and see what the state of the release was at that point

  - i.e. were there any stories previously assigned to the release that now are not, and vice versa
  - Seems that a release is not treated as a container in the lookback API, so not sure how to do this explicitly
- I could simply “brute force” it and check the release on every story at the end of each iteration, but it seems like overkill

What is the recommended way to get out this information?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the lookback api and get all stories at a certain date with the release set as you expect.  Then you can change the date field and see the story count changes, or you could parse the user story numbers and track changes.  (added or subtracted stories)

Something like:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        fetch: ['Name','ScheduleState', 'Project', 'Release'],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records) {
                   //get count or process the records here.
                }
            }
        },
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'Release',
                operator: '=',
                value: releaseReference
            }
            {
                property: '__At',
                value: dateString
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate approach I used here was recommended by Rally, behind the Release Scope Change app there is the beginnings of what I need, so I am modifying that app.

- Basically it gives me the list of all stories/defects that have ever been added/removed from a release
- Next steps (successful so far...)

  - Remove duplicate entries from the list
  - Add a column for each calendar month in the release
  - Add a flag against each story in the month it was added/removed

I will extend this later with an iteration breakdown, but for now it's pretty good.